# How to run my very very basic OS kernel in virtualbox?

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel, virtualbox

I am reading the following post :
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/zv07M4Gy/
This post is about creating a simple OS kernel which displays a greeting on the screen...
I read the whole tutorial, but I'm still confused on how to make it work,
I have installed the gcc, nasm, virtualbox, ... all the other tools listed on that site,
But, I'm not much familiar with those tools except gcc ( because I use gcc for c++/c ),
Are there any practical examples to take a look at, because I made all the files boot.asm, kernel.cpp, linker.ld and grub.cfg...
But I don't know how to run it !¿?
What should I do to make it run ?

Comment: [Try creating it yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+your+own+virtualbox+image)

Comment: @jonniejs I am learning to create a basic OS kernel, how can I create a whole OS on my own ?, that's why I'm trying the online resources...but I'm stuck with how to run my very very basic os in virtual box

Comment: Those instructions create an .iso disk image.  You then just create a new VM and in the properties mount the .iso as the 1st disk and boot the VM.

Comment: And I would suggest using bochs instead of virtualbox, bochs has a machine debugger available that allows you to step through the code actually being run on the VM. (It's possible to make your OS allow remote debugging but particularly in the early stages that is a tall order to implement). To do that with bochs you run bochsdbg instead of the regular bochs.

Comment: All of you thanks for comments !

Comment: you can use **QEMU** for Instruction Set Architecture Level Virtualization . Then you can use `qemu-system-i386 -kern kern` to run your os (where kern is the name of your executable made by the linker).